# Include entire Foreign Key object when retrieving an object

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to carry over object relationship functionality from a php backend to a python backend. In the php application you were able to have a call like so:

```
~api/v1/cats/5b40b6eb-538f-a015-9196-1cc63cf8d7ae
```

That would return a result like this:

```
{
    id: "5b40b6eb-538f-a015-9196-1cc63cf8d7ae",
    name: "mittens",
    hatId: "0845de76-9d68-cfee-0ebb-473ccddf16bc",
}
```

The functionality that I am trying to replicate is that if you added an include param to the call with the name of foreign object like this:

```
~api/v1/cats/5b40b6eb-538f-a015-9196-1cc63cf8d7ae?include=hat
```

Then it would return the original object including the foreign key object

```
{
    id: "5b40b6eb-538f-a015-9196-1cc63cf8d7ae",
    name: "mittens",
    hatId: "0845de76-9d68-cfee-0ebb-473ccddf16bc",
    hat: {
        id: "0845de76-9d68-cfee-0ebb-473ccddf16bc",
        name: 'top hat',
    }
}
```

All that I've come across so far is select_related, HyperlinkedRelatedField, and prefetch_related; none of these seem to be able to get the above result when implemented.

Comment: [nested relationships](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using Django Rest Framework, and specifically look at [nested relationships](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).

The example given in the DRF docs matches what you're looking to do almost exactly (though note, it's a one-to-many field, while your example is a one-to-one field):

```
>>> album = Album.objects.create(album_name="The Grey Album", artist='Danger Mouse')
>>> Track.objects.create(album=album, order=1, title='Public Service Announcement', duration=245)
<Track: Track object>
>>> Track.objects.create(album=album, order=2, title='What More Can I Say', duration=264)
<Track: Track object>
>>> Track.objects.create(album=album, order=3, title='Encore', duration=159)
<Track: Track object>
>>> serializer = AlbumSerializer(instance=album)
>>> serializer.data
{
    'album_name': 'The Grey Album',
    'artist': 'Danger Mouse',
    'tracks': [
        {'order': 1, 'title': 'Public Service Announcement', 'duration': 245},
        {'order': 2, 'title': 'What More Can I Say', 'duration': 264},
        {'order': 3, 'title': 'Encore', 'duration': 159},
        ...
    ],
}
```

Comment: Cool; have you by any chance come across a way to implement them on an existing database without migration scripts?

Comment: If the FK relationship already exists, then there's no need to make any changes / migrations to the database. You should be able to set up a serializer that simply traverses the existing database relationships.